# Java and Firebird Embedded how to set up?

Tags: java, cross-platform, firebird, firebird-embedded

I would like to develop a Java application which use FireBird Embedded to store some data.
I am trying to make it this way: http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq350/

I don't know how I can set the "FIREBIRD environment variable" or how can I set parameters of the JVM.

My final goal is that the application (and firebird) can be copied to any Windows (or maybe Linux) machine and run on it without any configuration made by user. But first of all I just want to make it working on my Windows.

Please, help me. :)

Comment: Why firebird ???, you may find a Java-DB easier (e.g. H2 http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html, but there are other HSQLDB, etc).

Comment: IMHO Sqlite would do a better job for what you are trying to achieve. Especially if you want to allow the database file to be copied onto multiple platforms without any configuration made by the user.

Comment: H2 seems to be good. A pure Java solution is the best for cross-platform, and performance is not a important in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at the chapter 2 of [this](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/Jaybird_2_1_JDBC_driver_manual.pdf) tutorial. You don't need to set any environment variable. just need firebird driver, defualt user name which is (sysdba) and password (masterkey). You can use [flamerobin](http://www.flamerobin.org/%E2%80%8E) for the ease use of firebird.